# QuerySave not triggered after submit in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, submit, xpages

I have strange issue that do not work in Internet Explorer but works fine in Chrome.

I have a button that does a submit when the datasource is in edit mode

```
<xp:button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="TicketsaveButton" rendered="#{javascript:ticket.isEditable()}">
        Save
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" save="true" disableValidators="true">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:actionGroup>
                    <xp:openPage name="ticket.xsp" target="editDocument" documentId="#{javascript:ticket.getDocument().getUniversalID()}"></xp:openPage>
                </xp:actionGroup>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

when I click the first time the values are saved (QS triggered) but after that no click on the save button saves anything and the Query save event is not triggered

When I look in Dev Tools IE I can see that the request body of the "POST" contain the new value, but the response body is still the old value

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="view:_id1:_id365:_id391:description1"

newvalue
```

So if I do a first save it is saved, if I do a second save it does not save, but I noticed that sometimes that if I click the refresh button in IE I get the "resend form again" prompt and click ok to this and do this a few times the new values I entered earlier seem to be saved/applied.

- I am using IE10 but there is script in the page that change document mode to IE7 standards
- I have tried to refresh the panel programmatically upon load containing the data source but no luck
- There is validation fields on the form but no visible validation errors and the submit button is set to ignore validation errrors
- The data source is bound to a panel in a custom control

Any ideas how I can get this save to work everytime in IE?

Comment: Thomas, are you trying to create a Save as Draft button? I don't understand why you include an openPage action. Also, you are setting the label of the button inside the tags instead of using the value tag. Can that have an impact on how IE interprets the button?

Comment: Per, I did not write the code :-) When the button is clicked the form is submitted and the same document is opened again using the openpage action. Seem like a long shot that the lable is causing problems but I can check that next week. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the purpose of the button is to implement Save as Draft functionality. Try this instead:

```
<xp:button value="Save as Draft" id="buttonSaveAsDraft" rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true" disableValidators="true"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

You need to modify label and rendered logic to your needs, of course.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and removed the dojo part and added a label to the button but I get the same result. works fine in chrome but only one save in IE.